Resize image held in variable while preserving aspect ratio using PHP
There are tons of answers here in SO and elsewhere on the web about how to resize an image using PHP when the image is on disk. However, these do not work if the image is held in a variable. I believe this is because the images on disk are binary files whereas the images in a variable are held as strings but I don't know how to convert one to another.
How can I modify the following code using the GD library to work for an image held in a variable as opposed to one on disk?
function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $r = $width / $height;
    if ($crop) {
        if ($width > $height) {
            $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        } else {
            $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
        }
        $newwidth = $w;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        if ($w/$h > $r) {
            $newwidth = $h*$r;
            $newheight = $h;
        } else {
            $newheight = $w/$r;
            $newwidth = $w;
        }
    }
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    return $dst;
}

Call with

$img = resize_image(‘/path/to/some/image.jpg’, 200, 200);


The two replacement functions you'll need are:

getimagesizefromstring
imagecreatefromstring

As per the documentation these behave in the same way, but can deal with your image data that is in a variable as a string. As you refactor your code, just change your function to accept the entire image as string data as your input parameter.
